# Stubbing a Mongoose model with Sinon

Tags: node.js, mongoose, sinon

I want to create a stub for the Mongoose `save` method in a particular model, so that any instance of my model I create will call the stub instead of the normal Mongoose `save` method. My understanding is that the only way to do this is to stub the entire model like this:

```
var stub = sinon.stub(myModel.prototype);
```

Unfortunately, this line of code causes my tests to throw the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'states' of undefined
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this. The first is

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var myStub = sinon.stub(mongoose.Model, METHODNAME);
```

If you console log mongoose.Model you will see the methods available to the model (notably this does not include lte option).

The other (model specific) way is

```
var myStub = sinon.stub(YOURMODEL.prototype.base.Model, 'METHODNAME');
```

Again, the same methods are available to stub.

EDIT: Some methods such as save are stubbed as follows:

```
var myStub = sinon.stub(mongoose.Model.prototype, METHODNAME);
var myStub = sinon.stub(YOURMODEL.prototype, METHODNAME);
```

Comment: How would that work for chained queries? Something like `MYMODEL.findOne(...).where(...).gt(...).exec(callback)`

Comment: @Milovan Zogovic see my answer below

Comment: For Static Methods: `var myStub = sinon.stub(MYMODEL.schema.statics, STATICNAME);` if anyone's interested.  Great answer, @Jacob -- console.log suggestion helped me a lot

Comment: Worth noting that the first option for stubbing `save()` (stubbing the generic `Model` prototype), doesn't appear to work on mongoose anymore (mongoose version 4.11). Stubbing prototype of the custom model still appears to work.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look to [sinon-mongoose](https://github.com/gaguirre/sinon-mongoose). You can expects chained methods with just a few lines:

```
sinon.mock(YourModel).expects('find')
  .chain('limit').withArgs(10)
  .chain('exec');
```

You can find working examples on the repo.

Also, a recommendation: use `mock` method instead of `stub`, that will check the method really exists.

Comment: Does this depend on how the code is written, and not what the code is doing? The test should be valid whether the calls are chained or not in the code under test.

Comment: Should work. But if don't, please post an example :)

Comment: This does not work on the save method. And that's the method asked to mock by the poster.

Answer (score 7):

`save` is not a method on the model, it's a method on the document (instance of a model). Stated [here in mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html).

> Constructing documents
>
> Documents are instances of our model. Creating them and saving to the database is easy

Therefore, it will always be undefined if you're using your model to mock a `save()`

Going along with @Gon's answer, using [sinon-mongoose](https://github.com/gaguirre/sinon-mongoose) & [factory-girl](https://github.com/aexmachina/factory-girl) with `Account` being my model:

#### Will not work

```
var AccountMock = sinon.mock(Account)

AccountMock
  .expects('save') // TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property save as function
  .resolves(account)
```

#### *Will* work

```
var account = { email: 'sasha@gmail.com', password: 'abc123' }

Factory.define(account, Account)
Factory.build('account', account).then(accountDocument => {
  account = accountDocument

  var accountMock = sinon.mock(account)

  accountMock
    .expects('save')
    .resolves(account)

  // do your testing...
})
```

Comment: Looked all over the web for a sinon-mongoose compatible answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the whole object, try:

```
sinon.stub(YOURMODEL.prototype, 'save')
```

Make sure YOURMODEL is the class not the instance.

Comment: `save` is on the instance with Mongoose.

Answer (score 2):

Tangentially-related, but relevant...

I needed to mock a custom model method like:

```
myModelSchema.methods.myCustomMethod = function() {....}
```

To create a stub I did:

```
myCustomMethodStub = sinon.stub(MyModel.schema.methods, 'myCustomMethod').callThrough();
```

Answer (score 1):

As told by djv, the `save` method is on the document. So you can stub it this way:

```
const user = new User({
      email: 'email@email.com',
      firstName: 'firstName',
      lastName: 'lastName',
      userName: 'userName',
      password: 'password',
    });

stub(user, 'save').resolves({ foo: 'bar' });
```

Bonus, you can assert it with [Chai](https://www.chaijs.com/) and [Chai as promised](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) this way:

```
const promise = user.save();
await chai.assert.doesNotBecome(promise, { foo: 'bar' });
```