# Stub save Instance Method of Mongoose Model With Sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, sinon

I am trying to test a service function I use to save a widget using a Mongoose model. I want to stub out the save instance method on my model, but I cannot figure out a good solution. I have seen other suggestions, but none seem to be complete.

See... [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318972/stubbing-a-mongoose-model-with-sinon), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727616/stubbing-a-mongoose-model-using-sinon).

Here is my model...

```
// widget.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var widgetSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, default: ''}
});

var Widget = mongoose.model('Widget',  widgetSchema);

module.exports = Widget;
```

Here is my service...

```
// widgetservice.js

var Widget = require('./widget.js');

var createWidget = function(data, callback) {

    var widget = new Widget(data);
    widget.save(function(err, doc) {
        callback(err, doc);
    });

};
```

My service is very simple. It accepts some JSON data, creates a new widget, and then saves the widget using the "save" instance method. It then calls back passing an err and doc based on the outcome of the save call.

I only want to test that when I call createWidget({title: 'Widget A'})...

- The Widget constructor is called once with the data I passed to the service function
- The save instance method on the newly created widget object is called once
- EXTRA CREDIT: That the save instance method calls back with null for the err and with {title: 'Widget A'} for the doc.

In order to test this in isolation, I would probably need to...

- Mock or stub the Widget constructor so that it would return a mock widget object that I create as part of my test.
- Stub the mock widget object's save function so I can control what occurs.

I am having trouble figuring out how to do this with Sinon. I have tried several variations found on the pages of SO with no luck.

NOTES:

- I don't want to pass in an already constructed model object to the service because I want the service to be the only thing that "knows" about mongoose.
- I know this is not the biggest deal (to just test this with more of an integration or end-to-end test, but it would be nice to figure out a solution.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: "I don't want to pass in an already constructed model object to the service because I want the service to be the only thing that "knows" about mongoose." then you should use a dependency injection container and not rely on nodejs modules to inject dependencies like you are doing right now. or at the very least have a way to override Widget Class in your service.with setter injection,right now in my opinion your script is not testable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If were to test that, this is how I would approach it, first have a way to inject my mocked widget to the widget-service. I know there's [node-hijack](https://github.com/MathieuTurcotte/node-hijack), [mockery](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery) or something like [node-di](https://github.com/vojtajina/node-di), they all have different styles, I'm sure there's more. Choose one and use it.

Once I get that right, then I create my widget-service with my mock widget module. Then I do something like this(this is using [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/) btw):

```
// Either do this:
saveStub = sinon.stub();
function WidgetMock(data) {
    // some mocking stuff
    // ...
    // Now add my mocked stub.
    this.save = saveStub;
}


// or do this:
WidgetMock = require('./mocked-widget');
var saveStub = sinon.stub(WidgetMock.prototype, 'save');


diInject('widget', WidgetMock); // This function doesn't really exists, but it should
// inject your mocked module instead of real one.

beforeEach(function () {
    saveStub.reset(); // we do this, so everytime, when we can set the stub only for
    // that test, and wouldn't clash with other tests. Don't do it, if you want to set
    // the stub only one time for all.
});
after(function () {
    saveStub.restore();// Generally you don't need this, but I've seen at times, mocked
    // objects clashing with other mocked objects. Make sure you do it when your mock
    // object maybe mocked somewhere other than this test case.
});
it('createWidget()', function (done) {
    saveStub.yields(null, { someProperty : true }); // Tell your stub to do what you want it to do.
    createWidget({}, function (err, result) {
        assert(!err);
        assert(result.someProperty);
        sinon.assert.called(saveStub); // Maybe do something more complicated. You can
        // also use sinon.mock instead of stubs if you wanna assert it.
        done();
    });
});
it('createWidget(badInput)', function (done) {
    saveStub.yields(new Error('shhoo'));
    createWidget({}, function (err, result) {
        assert(err);
        done();
    });
});
```

This is just a sample, my tests sometimes get more complicated. It happens that most of the time, the backend calling function(here it is, widget.save) that I want to mock, is the one that I want it's behavior to change with every different test, so that's why I reset the stub everytime.

Here's also another example for doing similar thing: https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/blob/16b7f7c8d313917517ec834dbda05db117ec141c/apps/sms/test/unit/thread_ui_test.js#L1614

Comment: So, you would mock the entire Widget and have that injected into the method under test? Would you need to rewrite the method in a different way to support this approach? How would you handle that part of it, assuming your approach to the testing? Could you still use 'var widget = new Widget(data)'? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, either I just use the real implementation and override the functions with stubs or I just mock the object as much as I need it to use it. Here if you wanna just have `new Widget().save`, you just need a constructor with contains a `save` method and no more. I try to keep as simple as possible. I don't understand what do you mean by rewritng the method in a different way. Technically as long as you get your dependency injection right, you wouldn't have to care about it at the method level.

Comment: I understand. I accepted your answer, which is similar to Louis' answer because you answered first. Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin - Regarding this line
diInject('widget', WidgetMock);

Is this part of a framework?  If yes, which one?

Comment: In this line - diInject('widget', WidgetMock);

What is 'widget'?

Comment: @kamyFC Read the comment around it. That's just an imaginary function. It meant to show that, that's where you inject the mocked widget instead of the real widget.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would do it. I'm using [Mockery](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery) to manipulate the module loading. The code of `widgetservice.js` must changed so that it calls `require('./widget');`, without the `.js` extension. Without the modification, the following code won't work because I use the general recommended practice of avoiding extensions in `require` calls. Mockery is states clearly that the names passed to the `require` call must match exactly so.

The test runner is [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/).

The code follows. I've put copious comments in the code itself.

```
var mockery = require("mockery");
var sinon = require("sinon");

// We grab a reference to the pristine Widget, to be used later.
var Widget = require("./widget");

// Convenience object to group the options we use for mockery.
var mockery_options = {
    // `useCleanCache` ensures that "./widget", which we've
    // previously loaded is forgotten when we enable mockery.
    useCleanCache: true,
    // Please look at the documentation on these two options. I've
    // turned them off but by default they are on and they may help
    // with creating a test suite.
    warnOnReplace: false,
    warnOnUnregistered: false
};

describe("widgetservice", function () {
    describe("createWidget", function () {
        var test_doc = {title: "foo"};

        it("creates a widget with the correct data", function () {

            // Create a mock that provides the bare minimum.  We
            // expect it to be called with the value of `test_doc`.
            // And it returns an object which has a fake `save` method
            // that does nothing. This is *just enough* for *this*
            // test.
            var mock = sinon.mock().withArgs(test_doc)
                .returns({"save": function () {}});

            // Register our mock with mockery.
            mockery.registerMock('./widget', mock);
            // Then tell mockery to intercept module loading.
            mockery.enable(mockery_options);

            // Now we load the service and mockery will give it our mock
            // Widget.
            var service = require("./widgetservice");

            service.createWidget(test_doc, function () {});
            mock.verify(); // Always remember to verify!
        });

        it("saves a widget with the correct data", function () {
            var mock;

            // This will intercept object creation requests and return an
            // object on which we can check method invocations.
            function Intercept() {
                // Do the usual thing...
                var ret = Widget.apply(this, arguments);

                // Mock only on the `save` method. When it is called,
                // it should call its first argument with the
                // parameters passed to `yields`. This effectively
                // simulates what mongoose would do when there is no
                // error.
                mock = sinon.mock(ret, "save").expects("save")
                    .yields(null, arguments[0]);

                return ret;
            }

            // See the first test.
            mockery.registerMock('./widget', Intercept);
            mockery.enable(mockery_options);

            var service = require("./widgetservice");

            // We use sinon to create a callback for our test. We could
            // just as well have passed an anonymous function that contains
            // assertions to check the parameters. We expect it to be called
            // with `null, test_doc`.
            var callback = sinon.mock().withArgs(null, test_doc);
            service.createWidget(test_doc, callback);
            mock.verify();
            callback.verify();
        });

        afterEach(function () {
            // General cleanup after each test.
            mockery.disable();
            mockery.deregisterAll();

            // Make sure we leave nothing behind in the cache.
            mockery.resetCache();
        });
    });
});
```

Unless I've missed something, this covers all the tests that were mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks Louis. I think yours and the first answer are essentially similar, mocking and injecting the entire new capability for the save method. I accepted his as he was first. Thanks again!

Comment: This is not a duplicate though. Here sinon mocks are used instead of stubs. They are good things and at times when you wanna assert if your stub has been called with the arguments you want, you should use them. Though you can't call them with two different arguments and assert both: https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/issues/202

Comment: Thank you both for your help. If I could accept both, I would. --Kevin

Answer (score 3):

With current version of Mongoose you can use `create` method

```
// widgetservice.js
var Widget = require('./widget.js');

var createWidget = function(data, callback) {
  Widget.create(data, callback);
};
```

Then to test the method (using Mocha)

```
// test.js
var sinon = require('sinon');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Widget = mongoose.model('Widget');
var WidgetMock = sinon.mock(Widget);

var widgetService = require('...');

describe('widgetservice', function () {

  describe('createWidget', function () {

    it('should create a widget', function () {
      var doc = { title: 'foo' };

      WidgetMock
        .expects('create').withArgs(doc)
        .yields(null, 'RESULT');

      widgetService.createWidget(doc, function (err, res) {
        assert.equal(res, 'RESULT');
        WidgetMock.verify();
        WidgetMock.restore();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Also, if you want to mock chained methods use [sinon-mongoose](https://github.com/gaguirre/sinon-mongoose).