# Using Sinon to stub chained Mongoose calls

Tags: node.js, mongoose, sinon

I get how to stub Mongoose models (thanks to [Stubbing a Mongoose model with Sinon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318972/stubbing-a-mongoose-model-with-sinon)), but I don't quite understand how to stub calls like:

```
myModel.findOne({"id": someId})
    .where("someBooleanProperty").equals(true)
    ...
    .exec(someCallback);
```

I tried the following:

```
var findOneStub = sinon.stub(mongoose.Model, "findOne");
sinon.stub(findOneStub, "exec").yields(someFakeParameter);
```

to no avail, any suggestions?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've solved it by doing the following:

```
var mockFindOne = {
    where: function () {
        return this;
    },
    equals: function () {
        return this;
    },
    exec: function (callback) {
        callback(null, "some fake expected return value");
    }
};

sinon.stub(mongoose.Model, "findOne").returns(mockFindOne);
```

Answer (score 8):

Take a look to [sinon-mongoose](https://github.com/gaguirre/sinon-mongoose). You can expects chained methods with just a few lines:

```
sinon.mock(YourModel).expects('findOne')
  .chain('where').withArgs('someBooleanProperty')
  .chain('exec')
  .yields(someError, someResult);
```

You can find working examples on the repo.

Also, a recommendation: use `mock` method instead of `stub`, that will check the method really exists.

Comment: This gives me: "TypeError: sinon.stub(...).expects is not a function"

Comment: @schw4ndi you're using `sinon.stub` instead of `sinon.mock`. Tell me if that doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: @OllyJohn that's how `sinon` works: you can expect on a mock but not on a stub. 
That's why I recommend to use `mock` instead of `stub` if you can expect something from the mocked call.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to stub or spy the prototype functions of the created Query (using sinon):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

sinon.spy(mongoose.Query.prototype, 'where');
sinon.spy(mongoose.Query.prototype, 'equals');
const query_result = [];
sinon.stub(mongoose.Query.prototype, 'exec').yieldsAsync(null, query_result);
```

Answer (score 3):

I use promises with Mongoose and stub the methods like this:

```
const stub = sinon.stub(YourModel, 'findById').returns({
    populate: sinon.stub().resolves(document)
})
```

Then I can call it like:

```
const document = await YourModel.findById.populate('whatever');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Promise, you can try [sinon-as-promised](https://github.com/bendrucker/sinon-as-promised):

```
sinon.stub(Mongoose.Model, 'findOne').returns({
  exec: sinon.stub().rejects(new Error('pants'))
  //exec: sinon.stub(). resolves(yourExepctedValue)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Multiple mongoose method stub using below code.
Service code

```
 models.Match.findOne({ where: { id: ChangeInningInputType.id } })
      .then((match) => {
        if (!match) {
         throw Error('Match not found');
        }
        models.Match.update(
          { inning: ChangeInningInputType.inning },
          { where: { id: ChangeInningInputType.id } },
        );
        return resolve(match);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return reject(error);
      });
```

Testcase code

```
 it('Success test case for inning update', async () => {
    const bulkCreateStub = sinon
      .stub(models.Match, 'findOne')
      .resolves(inningResponse);

    const updateStub = sinon
      .stub(models.Match, 'update')
      .resolves(inningResponse);

    const aa = await changeInning(
      {},
      {
        ChangeInningInputType: inningRequest,
      },
    );
    console.log('updateStub===>', updateStub);
    expect(updateStub.calledOnce).to.equal(true);

    expect(bulkCreateStub.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
  });
```