# Using Sinon to stub a mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongoose, tdd, sinon

I am trying to stub a mongoose model to return a json value

the code that i have is

```
var valueToReturn = {
                      name:'xxxxx'
                     };

var stub = sinon.stub(MyModel.prototype,'findOne');

stub.returns(valueToReturn);
```

I get this error : TypeError:Attempted to wrap undefined property findOne as function

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28885743/1521933)

Comment: Here they are using the findOne method of mongoose.Model. I am trying to use MyModel.findOne because my export method has findOne being used for 2 different models. So i want to try and stub 2 different models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look to [sinon-mongoose](https://github.com/gaguirre/sinon-mongoose). You can expects chained methods with just a few lines:

```
// If you are using callbacks, use yields so your callback will be called
sinon.mock(YourModel)
  .expects('findById').withArgs('abc123')
  .chain('exec')
  .yields(someError, someResult);

// If you are using Promises, use 'resolves' (using sinon-as-promised npm) 
sinon.mock(YourModel)
  .expects('findById').withArgs('abc123')
  .chain('exec')
  .resolves(someResult);
```

You can find working examples on the repo.

Also, a recommendation: use `mock` method instead of `stub`, that will check the method really exists on the original object.

Comment: Are you the creator of sinon-mongoose?  You plug it in 7-8 different threads about mongoose testing.

Comment: @VtoCorleone yes, I shared it because I think it could be useful for others facing the same problem I had when mocking mongoose models :)