# Spying on a Mongoose save operation with Sinon.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mocha.js, sinon

I would like to write a test that verifies that a certain property will be saved using Mongoose, for instance:

```
var newUser = new userModel({
    id: /*something*/,
    gu: true
});

newUser.save(function (err, user) {
    /* ... */
    res.send(user.id);
});
```

In my tests, I want to make sure that the `gu` property is set to true. I can easily stub `save()`, however I can't verify that `gu` is set to true since `save()` is a function of the object and therefore it is not part of the parameters. Any ideas?

Comment: This has been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318972/stubbing-a-mongoose-model-with-sinon

Comment: No it hasn't. I even asked a follow-up question on that page as a follow-up. The distinction is that I want to spy on the values saved because I want to make sure, in my case, that `gu` is set to true. Also, it doesn't explain how to do it with chained calls.

Comment: Isn't possible to access the this context of the call through sinon? It should hold all the properties.